# Handle Selected Turns/Games in iOS Game Center App in Game Center Enabled App

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center, gamekit

I am creating a `GKTurnBasedMatch` Game Center-enabled app. I've successfully implemented `GKLocalPlayerListener` methods to listen for events, such as `player:receivedTurnEventForMatch:didBecomeActive:` and other methods. Additionally, if a user taps on an *existing* match in the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` (for example, if `showExistingMatches` is set to `YES`), I can handle the event in the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` method `turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:didFindMatch:`.

However, I want to handle tapping on the various controls to view a match within the **iOS system Game Center app**.

For example, if I navigate to the Game Center iOS pre-installed app (not my app), tap on the Turns tab, tap on the row for my app, tap on a match/turn, and then tap on "View Game" or "Accept Invite" or "Play your turn", I want to handle these match-specific actions in my app.

When these items are tapped, my app indeed launches, but as far as I can tell from reading the documentation, there is no way to get extra information about *which match the user tapped*, so I can appropriately show that match.

Comment: I haven't found a way, either. If you're not in any app, and you get the alert view saying it's your turn, and choose the button to open your app, then receivedTurnEventForMatch fires (which tells you the match in question). But when the game center app launches your app, the event doesn't fire and there's no info passed in the arguments or env variables, that I can find. Seems like another half-baked aspect of GKTurnBasedMatch IMO.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you register the listener after authentication?              `GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().registerListener(self)`

Comment: See @sdc's answer below, it seems there is no solution for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has chosen to remove this feature.

Their documentation is inaccurate. I opened a bug with Apple to investigate further. Here is the disheartening proof.

[image: Apple bug report]